# best way to make an array of 2 child classes in java

Tags: java

First off I am new to java and am teaching my self.

my file structure is:

1. ParentClass.java
2. ChildClass1.java
3. ChildClass2.java
4. MyChildClasses.java

both ChildClass1 and 2 extend the ParentClass.
and MyChildClasses has a my main method that works with the child classes

In MyChildClasses main looks like this

```
    ChildClass1[] myClass1 = new ChildClass1[5]
    ChildClass2[] myClass2 = new ChildClass2[5]

    for(int i = 0; i > 5; i++)
    {
        //Setting the ClassID #'s
        myClass1[i] = new ChildClass1((100+i))
        myClass2[i] = new ChildClass2((100+i), (i+1))
    }
```

I am wanting to see if there is a way to make this into 1 array that can have both child classes in it?...

making it much easier to print out on screen.

Comment: Create an array of ParentClass and let it store instances of the ChildClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the array as `ParentClass[]` and assign instances of `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` into it.

You'd be better served with a java.util.List though:

```
List<ParentClass> list = new List<ParentClass>();
list.add(new ChildClass1());
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ParentClass[] myClasses = new ParentClass[10];
```

`myClasses` will be able to accept objects of type `ParentClass`, or any class that extends it such as `ChildClass1` or `ChildClass2`.